# WordPress custom REST API endpoint not returning the data

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using the following code to register a custom WordPress endpoint:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
  register_rest_route('custom', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'return_custom_data',
  ));
});

function return_custom_data(){
  return 'test';
}
```

However, this is the result I'm getting when sending a request to it:

```
{'namespace': 'custom', 'routes': {'/custom': {'namespace': 'custom', 'methods': ['GET'], 'endpoints': [{'methods': ['GET'], 'args': {'namespace': {'required': False, 'default': 'custom'}, 'context': {'required': False, 'default': 'view'}}}], '_links': {'self': 'http://localhost/index.php/wp-json/custom'}}}, '_links': {'up': [{'href': 'http://localhost/index.php/wp-json/'}]}}
```

It does recognize the endpoint, but the data I specified in the callback isn't returned.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check `register_rest_route` document in wordpress.org there are four arguments you can pass in that function. First two arguments are required.

Use below code to work with custom endpoint

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'custom_endpoints' );
function custom_endpoints() {
  register_rest_route( 'custom', '/v2', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'custom_callback',
    ));
}


function custom_callback() {
    return "custom";
}
```

Endpoint will be `http://localhost/index.php/wp-json/custom/v2`

Tested and works well.

Answer (score 0):

Below is full code to register custom end point and how to call it.

```
<?php

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {

$namespace = 'custom_apis/v1';

  register_rest_route( $namespace, 'get_helloworld', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'helloworld',
  ) );



  function helloworld(){

      return 'Hello world';
  }

  } );

?>
```

How to call your custom end point.

```
http://domain_name/wp-json/custom_apis/v1/get_helloword
```